# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in angular

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome, angular5

1. I'm trying to submit my form which has name and email and submit button. When I click on the submit button the page is not redirecting to another page, but instead it shows me this error in console:

   ```
   ERROR 
   HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}
       error: ProgressEvent
       bubbles: false
       cancelBubble: false
       cancelable: false
       composed: false
       currentTarget: XMLHttpRequest {__zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: "http://localhost:44371/api/InsertParticipant", __zone_symbol__loadfalse: Array(1), __zone_symbol__errorfalse: null, __zone_symbol__xhrScheduled: true, …}
       defaultPrevented: false
       eventPhase: 0
       isTrusted: true
       lengthComputable: false
       loaded: 0
       path: []
       returnValue: true
       srcElement: XMLHttpRequest {__zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: "http://localhost:44371/api/InsertParticipant", __zone_symbol__loadfalse: Array(1), __zone_symbol__errorfalse: null, __zone_symbol__xhrScheduled: true, …}
       target: XMLHttpRequest {__zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: "http://localhost:44371/api/InsertParticipant", __zone_symbol__loadfalse: Array(1), __zone_symbol__errorfalse: null, __zone_symbol__xhrScheduled: true, …}
       timeStamp: 157745.79999991693
       total: 0
       type: "error"
       __proto__: ProgressEvent
       headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
       message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
       name: "HttpErrorResponse"
       ok: false
       status: 0
       statusText: "Unknown Error"
   ```

> Failed to load resource : net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET at
>   localhost:44371/api/InsertParticipant

2. Here I'm doing a webAPI using c#.net where at localhost:44371/api/InsertParticipant.
3. When i click on submit the page should redirect from  http://127.0.0.1:4200/register  to 
   http://127.0.0.1:4200/quiz, but it is not redirecting to http://127.0.0.1:4200/quiz.
4. If you need more details I will help you.
5. What is the issue in the code?
6. How to remove the error? If needed I will give you a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the similar problem. In my case the solution was very trivial: Webapi in fact was launched on **https**://localhost:44381, but in my js client I tried to fetch data from http://localhost:44381. So, look carefully to link where your api launched.